# detect if url contains language with jquery

Tags: jquery, url, translation

I need to change the images in a jquery slider depending on the current language. It will show up in the url as /fr/ or /de/ etc. How would I pull that part out of the url? My jQuery skills are getting better, but still pretty basic.

Comment: There is not enough information to answer this question.

Comment: You can get the url with `window.location.href`, you would then just need to parse the string. No jQuery needed.

Comment: I don't think there's any way to do this with jQuery but if you are bold enough to use vanilla JavaScript `window.location.href` will give you the url

Answer (score 2):

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf('/fr/')!=-1) {
    //French stuff
}
```

Comment: you probably wanna put some `/` around that or test that there's one in front and fr in the end of the string. www.friedfriends.fr/frontpage will have quite a few false positives

Comment: @RuneFS - good point, just wrote a quick example and did'nt think about that !

Comment: Thank you so much!